# Service Worker (sw-precache) issue

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I generate a service worker with sw-prechache in my PWA. Everything worked fine so far and all files were cached. Now the file script.js has become too big, because I embed some libraries with "require", so there is only one script file. Now the script.js file is no longer in the list of the generated service worker. Is that because the file is too big? If I remove some libraries, the file is back in the list. But I need these libraries.

Here is some code:

```
gulp.task("generate-service-worker", function(callback) {
    swPrecache.write(path.join(outputDir, "service-worker.js"), {
        staticFileGlobs: [
            outputDir + "**/*.{js,html,json,css,png,jpg,gif,svg,eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}"],
        importScripts: ["push.js"],
        navigateFallback: ["index.html"],
        stripPrefix: outputDir
    }, callback);
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By default, `sw-precache` won't precache files that are over 2 megabytes in size.

If you'd like to override that, you can set the [`maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes` config parameter](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache#maximumfilesizetocacheinbytes-number) to something larger.